# PHP mb_ereg_replace deleting additional characters beyond each unicode search target

Tags: php, regex, string, unicode, replace

I have text with unicode soft hyphens (U+00AD) that I wish to remove. I'm attempting to do this with PHP's mb_ereg_replace() function. It's finding the soft hyphens, but the replace procedure is removing both the soft hyphens and the first character that immediately follows them.

My code is:

```
$text_cleansed = mb_ereg_replace('[\u00AD]', '', $text);
```

For example, if `$text` were `"en-dur-ance"` (with the hyphens shown here being the invisible unicode soft hyphens), then `$text_cleansed` would be `"enurnce"`; `-d` and `-a` have been removed, when for each soft hyphen *only* the soft hyphen should be removed. `mb_ereg_replace` has therefore removed each soft hyphen *and* the first character that follows it. Surely, I must be feeding incorrect arguments into the function.

What is causing this behavior, and what would be the correct arguments for the function?

Comment: And if your input is `1001`, the output should be `11` - PHP regex does not support `\u` notation. Use `preg_replace` with `\x{}` notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP regex does not support `\u` notation. The symbols in your regex are treated as separate entities, not as a hex notation (as '\u', '0', 'A', 'D').

Use preg_replace with `\x{}` notation with `/u` modifier (necessary to interpret the pattern and the input string as Unicode strings):

```
preg_replace('~\x{00AD}~u', '', $s)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/vddsAX)

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't been able to find documentation to that effect anywhere, and all of the mb_ereg_replace user-contributed examples were using the notation I had employed. Is there a way to do this with mb_ereg_replace, though?

Comment: I have never used `mb_ereg_replace`. I have just tried with `echo mb_ereg_replace('[\x{00AD}]', '', $s);` and it seems to work the same way as `preg_replace` (PHP 5.6.4).

Answer (score -1):

What stribizhev has written is correct. It's a matter of syntax that isn't clear in the PHP mb_ereg documentation. I'm answering after already marking his second response as the answer, because his third response has the specific answer to my original question (re: multi-byte strings--mb--as opposed to regular strings).

1) If non-multi-byte strings are used, `preg_replace('~\x{00AD}~u', '', $text)` is the solution.

2) If multi-byte strings are used, `mb_ereg_replace('[\x{00AD}]', '', $text)` is the solution.

It's a matter of syntax, obscure to those not experienced in regex work. With luck, this will help someone else with a similar problem.

Answer (score -1):

If your string is UTF8 encoded, you don't need to take in account that your string is multi-byte to remove a character from the ASCII range (00-7F) since these bytes aren't used to compose other multi-byte characters. In this case, you can use `str_replace`:

```
$result = str_replace('-', '', $text);
```